# How to change only the mtime of a directory?

Tags: files, timestamps

I am trying to change just the mtime of a directory by adding files or sub directories but that changes the ctime of the file too. Is there any way to just change the mtime without affecting the ctime or atime?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible because *ctime* is changed always if there is a change of *mtime*. Here is the explanation:

Let's see from file perspective:

**ctime** is the inode/file change time, it means that ctime is updated when the file attributes are changed, like changing the owner or the permission.

**mtime** is the file modify time, it's updated when you modify the content of a file.

Most of the times *ctime* and *mtime* will be the same, unless **only** the file attributes are updated. In that case only the *ctime* gets updated.

Now from a directory perspective:

A directory is a special kind of file and its content is a set of (filename, i-node) tuples. The *mtime* of the directory is updated when a tuple is added, removed or changed, it means when a file or directory is added, deleted or renamed, **mtime** changes and it triggers a change of **ctime**.

*When the metadata of the directory changes* (owner, group, mode), mtime is NOT updated *but ctime does*.

Comment: I don't understand, that from directory perspective why the mtime change triggers a ctime change?

Comment: @beginer: _any_ change in `mtime`, be it a file or directory, triggers a `ctime` update. That's because `ctime` tracks metadata modification, and `mtime` is part of the metadata.

Comment: @MestreLion got it, thanks