# Is ctime on linux always greater or equal as mtime?

Tags: files, filesystems, timestamps

I'm trying to clear out how the timestamps of a file on linux work.

In this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464) is stated:

> Modify - the last time the file was modified (content has been modified)
>
> Change - the last time meta data of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)

but every time I change  the file contents the ctime is also altered. It leads to me to think that it's like a change reaction:

1. The change in file contents triggers a change in mtime
2. The change in mtime (file metadata) triggers a change in ctime

If that's true, then ctime will allways be >= than mtime.

Is this assumption correct on every situation? (assuming the system time is never altered manually)

Comment: Yes, see also [How to change only the mtime of a directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191391)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: you can set *mtime* (modification time) and *atime* (access time) to arbitrary timestamps (within the limits of the `time_t` data type, including dates in the *future*.  After doing this, *ctime* will be the *current* time.

The [`utimes`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimes.html) function (which updates *mtime* and *atime*) accepts a pair of [`timeval`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_time.h.html) structures, which combine `time_t` (seconds) and and microseconds, potentially increasing the resolution, but not limited to times in the past.